# How to trigger refresh of a div unit on a page (Example given)

Tags: javascript, page-refresh

I am checking out this link : http://www.businessinsider.com/the-worlds-weirdest-etfs-that-you-can-trade-today-2011-10#market-vectors-gaming-etf-nyse-bjk-1

The page is a slideshow where the user can either press the Next/Previous button or use the right/left arrow keys to navigate through the slideshow. Everytime the user does a navigation, the ad unit on the right sidebar does a refresh. Any idea how this can be effected?

Answer (score 3):

The advertisement is displayed in an `iframe` (so it is not a simple `div`, in which case you would have to reload content using Ajax).

In the event handler for the navigation buttons, you simply have to reload this `iframe`.

You can either do this by using [`location.reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location#reload):

```
document.getElementById('myiframe').reload(true);
/*"true" means the URL should not be reloaded from cache*/
```

or setting the `src` to its current value:

```
var myIframe=document.getElementById('myiframe');
myIframe.src=myIframe.src;
```